# JTable and DefautlTableModel not refreshing

Tags: java, swing, jtable, defaulttablemodel

MyTableModel extends DefaultTableModel, everything looks and works correctly.

I have one editable column, and the setValueAt() is being called, and the database updated.

However the table itself is not being refreshed ?

I override, `getColumName()`, `getRowCount()`, `isCellEditable()`, `getColumClass()`, and `setValueAt()` - which gets called, and fires the database update.  The model is backed by a list, which is updated in setValueAt().

And the model is set simply by `myTable.setModel(myTableModel);`

Comment: Over 15k reputation and you still can't format your question properly, how is that possible?

Comment: Show code of `setValueAt()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you call `super.setValueAt()` in your code?

Looks like your changes skips events firing.

Answer (score 1):

Call [`fireTableCellUpdated()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html#fireTableCellUpdated%28int,%20int%29) at the end of `setValueAt()` method. It must help you.

Comment: not for DefaultTableModel, this notifiers is there and correctly

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to refresh the cache of the TableModel.
In order to do it you can override fireTableDataChanged() and call the super method at the end of the overriding.